# Verify that c# Embedded Resource matches file

Tags: c#, stream, embedded-resource, checksum, system.io.file

I know that this is may be a question without one 'right' answer

I have a C# windows application that has an embedded resource included in the assembly. I've been trying to come up with a way to compare the contents of my resource stream to determine if the contents of that stream matches a particular file on the file system.

e.g.

```
using(var resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"Manifest/Resource/Path/thing.exe"))
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(@"File/System/Path/thing.exe", FileMode.Read))
    // Compare Contents (thing.exe may be an older version)
    if(CompareStreamContents(resourceStream, fileStream))
    {
        /* Do a thing */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Do another thing*/
    }
```

Is there a better way than simply doing a byte-by-byte comparison? Thoughts? (and thanks in advance!)

Comment: You might hash the contents of the two streams, base64 encode the two hashes into string variables, then just do a simple a == b compare of the strings.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't know about `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`. I'm going to give this a shot and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment:

```
    private bool CompareStreamContents(Stream resourceStream, Stream fileStream)
    {
        var sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hash1 = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(ReadToEnd(resourceStream)));
        var hash2 = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(ReadToEnd(fileStream)));
        return hash1 == hash2;
    }

    private byte[] ReadToEnd(Stream stream)
    {
        var continueRead = true;
        var buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (continueRead)
        {
            var size = stream.Read((byte[])buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            else
            {
                continueRead = false;
            }
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

If you plan on doing something else with the streams after the compare, you may want to set the stream position back to origin before returning from the compare method.